# How to configure AutoMapper for list of sub object, and how to use ProjectTo<> in query?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a model `Template` with `List<Symbol> symbols`, and an equivalent ViewModel `TemplateJS` with `List<SymbolJS>`. When I query for a `Template`, `ProjectTo<TemplateJS>` seems to throw an Exception and I'm not sure why.

Exception: "**Argument types do not match**"

I would also like to `Include` `Symbol` in my query but I'm not exactly sure how to map that object as well. Would this need be done in a separate query?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

---

Models :

```cs
public class Template
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
        public List<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }
    }

public class Symbol
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public Template Template { get; set; }
        public char Letter { get; set; }
        public string ImgSource { get; set; }
    }

public class TemplateJS
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SymbolJS> Symbols { get; set; }
    }

public class SymbolJS
    {
        public char Letter { get; set; }
        public string ImgSrc { get; set; }
    }
```

AutoMapper :

```cs
CreateMap<Template, TemplateJS>()                
            .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<Symbol, SymbolJS>()
            .ReverseMap();
```

Query :

```cs
public async Task<TemplateJS> GetTemplateAsync(int Id)
        {
            try
            {

                var q = await _dbContext.Template
                                 //   .Include(x => x.Symbols)
                                .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
                                .ProjectTo<TemplateJS>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
                 return q;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Can you let me know if this works : [link](https://gist.github.com/roonz11/949a7bc73550d58b0d2b52295b44422a)

Comment: The validation says that `Symbols` cannot be mapped. But I don't think EF supports dictionaries. You can try it in an EF query without AM, just to confirm.

Comment: But if you define a DTO and use a `List`, things should work out.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu. I ended up changing it to a DTO and it worked fine.